# How to hide powered by google in google sites

Tags: google, google-sites

[image: How to disable/remove Report Abuse|Powered By Google Sites] How to disable/remove Report Abuse|Powered By Google Sites in google sites at the bottom of the page. I have used some css attributes. but the sites says those attributes are not permitted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't.  It violates Google's terms of service which you agreed to in order to create that Google site.
 If you do not wish to have a "powered by" link, you can try to use another provider for your website.

Comment: Could you tell the sites which offer such facilities.

Comment: @AUmarMukthar Is it to hard to Google that?